# Are HTTP Headers configured by the CDN or by the application?

Tags: http-headers, cdn

This is kind of a theoretical question, and I guess it may be too broad or unclear.

Foobar is an application serving users across the internet. It relies on a CDN to improve its resiliency, speed, etc to serve people wherever they are.

- Are the HTTP headers (received by the client) defined by the CDN, or by the Foobar application (implying the CDN will forward them)?
- If both are possible, what are the pros and cons of either?

Comment: depends on your CDN

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal answer. What gets done with/to headers depends both on the request, the specific CDN, the specific header and your site configuration (that includes both  the headers your backend/origin server includes in the response and how you configure your site in the CDN).

Assume that by default the majority of **headers  will be stripped** from the response generated by a back-end/origin server and only a (minimal) **subset of headers will be set** in the response sent by the CDN.

Some (CDN specific) headers *might* be **added** by the CDN according to your policies or by default. For example Fastly adds a [`x-served-by:` header](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/http/http-headers/X-Served-By/)  by default and CloudFront allows you to set and optional  [`Server-Timing:` header](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-response-headers.html) to facilitate debugging CDN operations.

Some headers *might* be ***preserved*** from your back-end server. For example `Cache-control:` and `Expires:` headers are fairly common ones. See for example: [Cloud Front docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html)

Some *might* be ***adjusted*** by the CDN in specific ways.  For example see how Fastly deals with a [`Date:` header](https://developer.fastly.com/reference/http/http-headers/Date/) set in the origin.

---

### Reasons to set headers at the CDN

Rather than allowing each application to do their own thing, or not do anything you set a single policy for all your sites and applications at the CDN level.

Good examples are [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) policies.

You may choose to only set/add a specific header at the CDN when the origin does not, but use the value from the origin if it is set there.

etc. etc.

---

### Reasons to preserve headers set at the origin

The application (developer) knows best what the application needs.

Overriding the default caching policy with a `Cache-Control: private, no-store` is a text book example that comes to mind.

etc. etc.